# Execute route without maximum execution time exceeded in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to call a route which will never stop. It always will be execute. My application is laravel appliation. Here is my route and tried with curl in centos7 server as well as windows server

```
curl https://test.com/reuuning-service
```

There I used **wait()** . Its working but problem after 1 minute it will terminate with **maximum execution time exceeded** how can I prevent that. I wan to execute always. I also tried with following within function

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '10000000');
```

But not worked . But I am realizing is not better way . I wan to execute always not constant time.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`. This indicates that there is no time limit for execution.